# Eigen product of the zero quaternion and any vector is not zero, is this a bug?

Tags: c++, eigen, quaternions

I'm using Eigen 3.3.7 and its quaternions to perform transformations on a set of vectors.

I needed to perform the product of a quaternion (that may be the zero-quaternion) with a vector. The problem is that when the quaternion IS the zero quaternion (zero real and vector parts), the value returned is the vector itself.

What I have understood by the Hamilton product definition is that, if the quaternion is the zero-quaternion, the product should return the zero-vector. Am I wrong?

The following snippet shows the issue, I was expecting vector `sv` to be the all zero, but it is not. Is this a bug?

```cpp
Eigen::Quaterniond q{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
Eigen::Vector3d v{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
auto sv = q * v;
```

Cheers and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've to admit that the doc of this [`operator*`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1RotationBase.html#a09a4757e7aff7a95bebf4fa8a965a4eb) is not crystal clear, but it is semantically equivalent to:

```
q.toRotationMatrix() * v
```

because `Eigen::Quaternion` has been designed to represent rotation only. In your case, since the null quaternion `q` is not unitary, it does not represent any rotation, and the return value is undefined.

See [bug 560](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/issues/560) for further details and discussions.